# Which correlation coefficient indicates the strongest relationship between two variables?

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to understand correlation coefficients, and seem to be missing something.

For example,

Correlation coefficient: Indicates the direction, positively or negatively of the relationship, and how strongly the 2 variables are related. I understand that the strength can vary from 0-1 and I thought I understood that positive or negative simply had to do with the direction of the correlation.

This question is part of my review and I don't understand why my answer is incorrect...

**Which correlation coefficient indicates the strongest relationship between two variables?**

**a) -0.85 - This was my answer which I thought was the closest to one (meaning strongest**

b)1.94

**c)0.58 - This is what the textbook says is the correct answer, but why?**

d)0.19

Thanks for your help!

Comment: seems like the "strongest" is meant to be the "most positive" - wich would an arguable definition in my opinion.

Comment: By correlation, do you mean [Pearson's coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) or something else? If so, $1.94$ is not even valid value, so it's out of question. See [interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Interpretation) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Yes, I knew that 1.94 wasn't a valid choice so that immediately eliminated that question, but I thought the strongest correlation coefficient should be a) -0.85

Comment: I'm guessing $1.94$ is a typo and $0.94$ was intended. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If the textbook is consequent then it would say that a relationship characterized by correlation coëfficient $0.01$ (almost indepent) is stronger than one with coëfficient $-0.99$. In my view your answer is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks guys! I think I will email my prof and see if the answer is a typo?